# Returning a specific number of datetime results closest to now

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a quiz application. Let's say I have four quizzes (that should run at 5 PM, 6 PM, 7 PM, and 8 PM), I represent it by setting a `.datetime` called `game_start` in the `Quiz` model.

Next, I want to show the user when the *next 3 quizzes* are coming up by datetime. I know I can do that by comparing `game_start` to `Time.now` like so:

```
  <p>Upcoming Game #1: <%= Quiz.where("game_start >= ?", Time.now).order(game_start: :asc).first.topic %></p>
  <p>Upcoming Game #2: <%= Quiz.where("game_start >= ?", Time.now).order(game_start: :asc).second.topic %></p>
```

I found someone approaching a similar problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157788/display-the-closest-future-time-to-now-from-database), but they were not trying to return multiple matches.

So it sort of works, but that does not follow DRY. Is it possible to specify that I want to return the first three results closest to `Time.now` instead of doing them individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `limit` to retrieve only 3. In your controller:

```
@quizzes = Quiz.where("game_start >= ?", Time.now).order(game_start: :asc).limit(3)
```

Then in your view iterate over @quizzes to display each quiz:

```
<% @quizzes.each_with_index do |quiz, index| %>
  <p>Upcoming Game #<%= index + 1 %>: <%= quiz.topic %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Better to add it as a scope in the model `scope :upcoming, -> (n) { order(game_start: :asc).limit(n) }`